# Passing text box values in an event handler

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events

I have the following code to validate two text box entries to make sure that they are valid dates.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass the text box value as an argument so I can use the method to handle the text validation of two different text boxes.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub txtBirthdate_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtBirthdate.Validating, txtSpouseBirthday.Validating

    Try
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sender.ToString) Then
            'Do Nothing
        Else
            Dim ReturnDate As DateTime
            ReturnDate = validator.CheckIsValidDate(sender.ToString)
            txtBirthdate.Text = ReturnDate.ToShortDateString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `sender` object to a `TextBox` to get at the properties:

```
Private Sub txtBirthdate_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) _
  Handles txtBirthdate.Validating, txtSpouseBirthday.Validating

  Try
    With DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
      If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(.Text) Then
          'Do Nothing
      Else
          Dim ReturnDate As DateTime
          ReturnDate = validator.CheckIsValidDate(.Text)
          .Text = ReturnDate.ToShortDateString
      End If
    End With
  Catch ex As Exception
      Throw
  End Try
End Sub
```